# Why java annotation syntax has () [parentheses]?

Tags: java, annotations

Why in "java" when you declare a "parameter" of an "annotation" you have to put "pair of parentheses" after the parameter, annotation are anyway "very different" form "interface" syntactically, so why this weird syntax...I know it has something to do with, that annotation are managed using interface behind the scenes or something, but what exactly?

Comment: Because annotation elements are "methods".

Comment: welcome to stackoveflow. Take a tour and get your first badge-https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

This is what a normal interface declaration would look like:

```
public interface Example {
    String method();
}
```

Note that when annotations were released, the java feature 'default methods for interfaces' wasn't around yet. The `default` keyword already existed (and has existed since java 1.0), solely as a thing you can put in a switch block, as the 'case' for 'it didnt match any of the cases'.

This is what an annotation interface definition looks like:

```
public @interface Example {
    String method();
}
```

or, if defaults are involved:

```
public @interface Example {
    String method() default "";
}
```

Note how parsing wise there is no difference between these two, other than the '@' symbol. In the 'default' case; yeah that's entirely new, but looking solely at that bit, it's not weird looking. The parentheses are, but not that bit.

The reason it's done this way is to not 'explode' parsing. Since the introduction of module-info in java9, if you want to write a parser for java, you mostly DO need an 'on the fly switching modes' parser; the "language specification" for a module file is so very different.

But that is a big step; the vast majority of parser libraries out there don't deal with this well, they can't switch grammars in the middle of parsing a source file.

Even if I can snap my fingers and break java (which, to be clear, java does not generally do: updating the language so that existing code now no longer compiles or means something else is a big step that is very rarely taken for obvious reasons. It restricts language design, though. That's the cost of being the world's most popular language*)... there are advantages here.

The way annotations work is that, if you at runtime obtain one, it acts like an object that is an instance of the annotation interface:

```
Example foo = Class.forName("foo.bar.Baz").getAnnotation(Example.class);
System.out.println(foo.method());
```

Note how it's not `foo.method`. It's `foo.method()`. And that has different reasons: fields, in java, are second-rate citizens. You can't put them in lambda method references (`ClassName::methodName` is valid java; there's no such thing for fields), they don't inherit, you can't put them in interfaces (fields in interfaces are automatically public, final, and static, i.e. constants. They don't decree a requirement to any implementing class, unlike methods in interfaces). That means fields as a general point of principle aren't used in public APIs in java. It'd be weird if in this instance they would be.

So, given that the params act like args-less method calls, it's convenient in that sense that you declare them that way as well in an `@interface` definition.

*) Give or take a few spots.

Comment: That makes sense, Thanks